# Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, android-studio, flutter-test

i am trying to achieve back page where in web veiw customer is moved out of the page instead going back which throws above error.StatefulWidget requires override method createState.All identations mark checked but still throwing error.where i am going wrong.

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomePage> createstate() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

late WebViewController _webViewController;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
toolbarHeight:0,
), // AppBar
body: WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async {
if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
_webViewController.goBack();
return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}

} ,
child: WebView(
initialUrl: 'https://www.example.com',
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
_webViewController = controller;
},
), // WebView
), // WillPopScope
); // scaffold
}
}
```

Comment: createstate needs a capital S like createState

Comment: @IvoBeckers not working test in AS

Answer (score 0):

In createState(), State's S should be Capital

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

   WebViewController _webViewController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight:0,
      ), // AppBar
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
            _webViewController.goBack();
            return false;
          }
          else {
            return true;
          }

        } ,
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
          },
        ), // WebView
      ), // WillPopScope
    ); // scaffold
  }
}
```

Comment: Error: Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function

Comment: Where you are calling this HomePage.?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Kindly check it now.

Comment: not working error's

Comment: Share complete code.

Comment: it is complete code void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp() to be added but not works

Comment: now check my answer.

Comment: not working test in AS

Comment: Have you tried creating a new flutter project and then use this page in that project.

Comment: yes i did still back not worked tested your code too

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: No error it just exits.tested on AS

Comment: on which device you are testing?

Comment: I have tested it by creating a new flutter project.It works fine

Comment: is this same code you shared

Comment: yes. it is same

Comment: I created only single page.

Comment: so i am able to veiw page but then it exit when back button is pressed.kindly check

Comment: bro there is only one page so, moving back does not find any other page.that's why it exists

Comment: so if you are using google click on a link opens a new page and on pressing back button should open previous page

Comment: it is working fine.

Comment: is their any way you can share ....

Comment: page is same as I have answered.

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: Their is no clarification where i can see in real time.Let me try.Will update you